# Hibernate Criteria one to many association, mutiple objects

Tags: hibernate

```
public class Company{

    private Long id;
    private String companyName;
    private List<Employee> employees;

}

public class Employee{

    private Long empid;
    private String fstName;
    private String lstName;
    private String sal;
    private Company company;

}
```

using Hibernate criteria api, I want to construct the following SQL

```
select compantName from company c,employee e where  c.id = e.companyid and
    (e.firstName like '%john%' and e.lastname like '%doe% ) or 
    (e.firstName like '%james%' and e.lastname like '%bond% ) or
    (e.firstName like '%mike%' and e.lastname like '%adams% )
```

Assume on UI user can search for firstname or last name or sal or company name or any one of 
combinations

Also more important, user can search for multiple employees at a time

I came up with the following code. Please suggest what is the best approach to handle above 
requirement

```
 DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria
                .forClass(Company.class);

    criteria.createAlias("employees","employees");            
    Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();

      for(Employee emp : employees){
        or.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike(
            "employees.fstName",emp.getFstName(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE),
        Restrictions.ilike(
            "employees.lstName",emp.getLstName(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
        criteria.add(or);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Company.class)
                   .CreateAlias("employees","emp",JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```

using criteria obtained above you can add Restrictions as you like 
use `Restrictions.ilike("emp.<propertyName>"...` for adding restrictions on `Employee`
use `Restrictions.ilike("this.<propertyName>"...` for adding restrictions on `Company`.
You can use `Restrictions.Or()` between the restrictions for `Company` and `Employee` with 
`Restrictions.And()` between restrictions for `Employee`.

The `JoinType` helps you select Company entities irrespective of the `Employee`s

Check out [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) for better understanding of using `ICriteria` in Hibernate.
*Pay special attention to the use of `CreateAlias` and `CreateCreteria` which help you to add `Restrictions` effectively.*

Hope this serves as a guideline to build your Criteria.

### Edit

adding this part to explain how to add the condition value.
Consider `Search` as a container object getting the info from the View to the Data access layer.

```
public class Search{
   private String Value;
   //getter and setter...
}
```

In your data access layer you can get the criteria from the top snippet of code and using

```
      search.getValue()!=null && !"".equals(search.getValue()){
             criteria.Add(Restrictions....);
      }
```

Comment: you can conditionally add the Restrictions, I have edited the answer, hope this helps, Do you need to find how the Restrictions are applied as well?